# For which $ l \in\mathbb{N} $ and $ \alpha\in[0,1] $ does u belong to the hoelder space $ C^{l,\alpha}(\overline {B_1(0)}) $?

Tags: holder-spaces

$$ u:\overline {B_1(0)}\subset\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}   $$
defined by : $$ u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2(1-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}) $$ 
Can I at first consider $$ x_1x_2  $$ 
and look if $$ x_1x_2\in C^{l,\alpha}(\overline {B_1(0)})\ ? $$ , 
 because the Hoelder space is a vector space .

Comment: what happened to $k?$

Comment: oh , sorry I mean  $$ l\in\mathbb{N} $$

Comment: I think $$  x_1x_2\in C^{l,\alpha}(\overline {B_1(0)}) $$ for all $$ l\in \mathbb{N} \ and \ \alpha\in[0,1] . $$